# Jersey on Jetty on Android throws ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: android, servlets, jetty, jersey

I'm trying to run Jersey on Jetty on Android.

I've created an Android that instantiate a Jetty Server with a Jersey Servlet. Anyway when I start Jetty and visit a REST resource (in my case: `http://192.168.1.12:8080/api/hello`) I get a ContainerException with message: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes. (see exception stack trace below).

Any idea why?

MORE DETAILS:

Logcat is giving the following SEVER WARNINGS.

`The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:`

SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private java.lang.ThreadLocal com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JSPTemplateProcessor.requestInvoker
SEVERE: Missing dependency for field: private java.lang.ThreadLocal com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JSPTemplateProcessor.requestInvoker

This is strange cause java.lang.ThreadLocal is available for [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) and HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse should be available since I've included servlet-api-2.5.jar in the libs folder.

Jersey is dependent on some javax libraries (jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar,jndi-1.2.1.jar,stax-api-1.0-2.jar) which I had to add to project and set the --core-library parameter temporary to ignore dex warning about javax packages as dependencies.

I also removed the following classes (RenderedImageProvider,DataSourceProvider,MimeMultipartProvider from package com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity from jersey core jar) to avoid dependencies on java.awt and javax.mail.

EXCEPTION trace:

```
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.makeUnavailable(ServletHolder.java:409)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:450)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:331)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:476)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:935)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:404)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:184)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:870)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1051)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:592)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:426)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:520)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:528)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Start Server Android Activity:

```
public class StartServerActivity extends Activity {

private Server webServer;

private final static String LOG_TAG = "Jetty";


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true");
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv6Addresses", "false");

    webServer = new Server(8080);

    ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.class);
    servletHolder.setInitParameter("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.famenu.server.resources");

    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(webServer, "/api", true, false);
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(servletHolder, "/hello");

    webServer.setHandler(servletContextHandler);


    try {
        webServer.start();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "started Web server");

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "unexpected exception starting Web server: " + e);
    }

}
```

}

Jersey Resource:

```
package com.famenu.server.resources;
```

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/")
public class HelloResource {

```
@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
public String getMsg() {

    return "Hello Resource";

}
```

}

I'm using Jetty 7.3.0.v20110203 , Jersey 1.12 , Android 1.6
I arrived till this point after another exception explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191346/jersey-on-jetty-on-android-throws-containerexception-no-webapplication-provide)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use package/any other scanning on .. not supported platforms.

Classnames property: com.sun.jersey.config.property.classnames should work for you (you need to explicitly declare all your root resource (@Path annotated) classes).

Comment: I've managed to run Jersey on Android!
You can find what I've done so far here: https://github.com/giorgio-zamparelli/jersey-android